# class object array inside struct

Tags: c++, arrays, class, struct, typedef

I need to put an array of class objects inside a struct.

The class inside a header file:

```
class aClass
{
private:
   int num;
public:
   aClass();
   ~aClass();
   int getNum();
   void setNum(int num);
}
```

The typedef inside a another header file

```
#include "aClass.hpp"

typedef struct
{
   aClass* classObject[3];
} newType_t;
```

At least the application

```
newType_t l_obj;
l_obj.classObject[1]->getNum();
```

The compiler works but at execution it comes to an segmentation fault. How to define the type correctly?

Thanks a lot
Alex

---

2nd try:

aClass.hpp

```
class aClass
{
private:
   int num;
public:
   aClass();
   ~aClass();
   int getNum();
   void setNum(int num);
};
```

app.hpp

```
class aClass;

typedef struct
{
   aClass classObject[3];
} newType_t;
```

app.cpp

```
newType_t l_obj;
l_obj.classObject[1].getNum();
```

g++

```
error: field 'classObject' has incomplete type
```

another try:

aClass.hpp

```
class aClass
{
private:
   int num;
public:
   aClass();
   ~aClass();
   int getNum();
   void setNum(int num);
};
```

app.hpp

```
#include "aClass.hpp"
typedef struct
{
   aClass classObject[3];
} newType_t;
```

app.cpp

```
newType_t l_obj;
l_obj.classObject[1].getNum();
```

g++

```
error: 'aClass' does not name a type
```

Comment: That isn't a class object in a structure; its a pointer array member. Declare it as `aClass classObject[3];` and reference them as `l_obj.classObject[n].getNum()` if you want three of them in the structure, or clarify your question for the problem you're *really* trying to solve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an array of *pointers*, which are uninitialized since you haven't told them where to point to. Using uninitialized pointers causes undefined behavior, which has manifested itself as a crash in your case.

You should have an array of objects since there is no use for pointers here:

```
aClass classObject[3];
```

Notice the removal of the `*` in the declaration. You can call the method by doing:

```
l_obj.classObject[1].getNum();
```

Also, `typedef struct` is unnecessary. You can name your structure directly:

```
struct newType_t { .. }
```

Comment: This solution was my first intention too. But I always got this compiler error: `error: field 'Semaphore' has incomplete type`

Comment: @Alex44 There's no use of the name "Semaphore" in the code you're showing us. Where are you using that name?

Comment: oh sorry - copy-paste error - it's really too late:
`error: field 'classObject' has incomplete type` it refers to `aClass classObject[3];`

Comment: @Alex44 You're missing a semicolon after your `aClass` struct definition.

Comment: @Alex44 Does  that fix it? The error itself doesn't make much sense though as `classObject` isn't a type (`aClass` is).

Comment: @Alex44 Your second example should compile  (as it does [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0328e8ce11636789)). The problem with your first example is that you are declaring an array of incomplete type `aClass`.

Comment: strange then the problem seems to be the include structure ?!

Comment: Yes - there are circular dependencies. I comment out one one of them an all things works fine :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You haven't initialized your pointers, so accessing them with `_obj.classObject[1]->` causes undefined behavior (like a segmentation  fault).

Answer (score 1):

```
newType_t l_obj;
```

This declares an instance of the `newType_t` class, which contains three pointers to instances of the `aClass` class.

The pointers are not initialized to point to any valid, instantiated object.

```
l_obj.classObject[1]->getNum();
```

This dereferences the 2nd pointer in the array. Since this pointer is not initialized to a valid, instantiated object. In your case, this results in a segmentation fault.